# Merge entire network account

Tags: support, stack-exchange, user-accounts, network-profile, merge-accounts

I currently have two stack exchange IDs, one linked to my old google ID with all my rep and accounts on multiple stackexchange sites. While another that is linked to my new gmail ID. I wanted to merge the two so I could start using only one gmail ID (the new one).

So far I have gone through the [Stackoverflow Contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) page, as well as the [Meta Stackexchange Contact Us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) page. I've also gone through [This help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) and a few questions like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist).

However no where is it explicitly mentioned whether all community accounts (stackoverflow, graphic design, UX design) etc would be merged or whether each one needs to be merged separately.

I currently have accounts with the following sub communities

1. stackoverflow.com
2. ux.stackexchange.com
3. superuser.com
4. codereview.stackexchange.com
5. graphicdesign.stackexchange.com
6. security.stackexchange.com

There are even more, but these are the most active ones. I am confused if there's a way to do it for all in a single go, or all have to be done manually.

This was even asked in the comment section [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18233) but went unanswered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Short answer

It'll all be done in one go.

#### Longer answer

Here's the anatomy, if you will, of a Stack Exchange account: you have a "network" account with individual community profiles attached to it. Your login credentials are also attached to the account, not individual profiles. When a merge happens, we always merge whole accounts, combine the login credentials, histories, etc.

Comment: Thanks a ton, just to confirm, so if I go to the stackoverflow contact page, select 'I need to merge profiles' and only give my stackoverflow profile link. It will automatically consider ux, graphic design profiles as well in the request. Have I got it right

Comment: @TDsouza Yep, that's exactly right.